# JavaScript Slider Plugin MightySlider - Need delay workaround

Tags: javascript, jquery

I purchased a slider plugin called MightySlider http://codecanyon.net/item/mightyslider-responsive-multipurpose-slider/5898508 I need a simple automated carousel that scrolls smoothly from the beginning to the end and then either loops or reverses direction. I've played with the settings enough to allow for a smooth scroll from beginning to end by setting the 'speed' and the 'cycling: {pauseTime}' parameters to be equal. No I have a delay of 20s (equal to the speed of the slider).

It's a long shot but can anyone help with the parameters to this or help me write a javascript hack to trigger the slider to start moving on page load or 1-2s after? Alternatively, could anyone recommend a different slider?

Site is here: http://smmcnyc.com/work/1919market/

JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/fhhdxnum/

```
    $(".frame").mightySlider({
     // Mixed options
      moveBy:       9000,        // Speed in pixels per second used by forward and backward buttons.
      speed:        20000,        // Animations speed in milliseconds. 0 to disable animations.
      easing:       'linear',    // Easing for duration based (tweening) animations.
      startAt:      10000,          // Starting offset in slides.
      startRandom:  0,          // Starting offset in slides randomly, where: 1 = random, 0 = disable.
      viewport:     'fill',     // Sets the cover image resizing method used to fit content within the viewport. Can be: 'center', 'fit', 'fill', 'stretch'.
      autoScale:    0,          // Automatically updates slider height based on base width.
      autoResize:   0,          // Auto resize the slider when active slide is bigger than slider FRAME.
      videoFrame:   null,       // The URL of the video frame to play videos with your custom player.
      preloadMode:  'nearby',   // Preloading mode for slides covers. Can be: 'all', 'nearby', 'instant'.

      // Scrolling
      scrolling: {
        scrollSource: null, // Selector or DOM element for catching the mouse wheel scrolling. Default is FRAME.
        scrollBy:     0,    // Slides to move per one mouse scroll. 0 to disable scrolling.
        hijack:       300   // Milliseconds since last wheel event after which it is acceptable to hijack global scroll.
      },

      // Pages
      pages: {
        pagesBar:       null, // Selector or DOM element for pages bar container.
        activateOn:     null, // Event used to activate page. Can be: click, mouseenter, ...
        pageBuilder:          // Page item generator.
          function (index) {
            return '<li>' + (index + 1) + '</li>';
          }
      },

      // Automated cycling
      cycling: {
        cycleBy:       'pages', // Enable automatic cycling by 'slides' or 'pages'.
        pauseTime:     20000, // Delay between cycles in milliseconds.
        loop:          1,    // Repeat cycling when last slide/page is activated.
        pauseOnHover:  0,    // Pause cycling when mouse hovers over the FRAME.
        startPaused:   0     // Whether to start in paused sate.
      },

    });
```

Advice or a workaround would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try nivo slider.

If you bought slider you can ask the customer support to do this.

Change cycling pouse time:

```
 cycling: {
    cycleBy:       'pages', 
    pauseTime:     1000,
```

or if this does not suit you:

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but this is how you can do this.
You will need to edit mightyslider.js

scroll down to function `requestHandler`  and after `timestamp=_now();` add (line ~2728) . These lines will start slide cycling if onLoadStart is true.

```
if(o.cycling.onLoadStart){
    o.cycling.onLoadStart += -50;
    if(o.cycling.onLoadStart == 0 || o.cycling.onLoadStart == true){
        cyclingActivate();
        o.cycling.onLoadStart = false;
    }
}
```

add this value into mightySlider.defaults array line ~6648

```
    // Automated cycling
    cycling: {
        .........................
        startPaused:   false,
        onLoadStart:   true
   }
```

now you can pass in additional option into mightySlider

```
 $(".frame").mightySlider({
     ........
     // Automated cycling
      cycling: {
        ..........
        startPaused:   0,
        onLoadStart: 1000    // true -- start immediately after load, 
                             // false --- with delayed start, 
                             // or enter time in miliseconds which is iess than delayed start.     
      }
    ...............
 });
```